# Send updated row to the bottom of table

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I have a table in PHP where I can modify its cells, then click a Save button and it adds them to a mysql table.

But what I want to do is to send that modified row to the bottom of the table. So the next time the user logs in, that row appears at the very bottom.

To be honest, I can't tell why this is useful or relevant, but boss orders are boss orders.

I've been looking for examples but I can't find anything, like it's not a very usual thing to do. Any help will be very useful.

UPDATE:

```
echo "<form name='form1' method='post'   action='actualizar.php?address_id=".$row[address_id]."'>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".$contador++."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row[address_1]."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row[address_2]."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row[city]."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row[postcode]."</td>";
echo "</form>";
```

The table is filled with data from a mysql table.

Comment: if its added to the db, does it show when you relaod the page ?

Comment: Can you give us some example code? A fiddle of the table would be nice.

Comment: add a column called `updated` or `added` of time datetime to store when the row was added and when writing your SQL query use an `ORDER BY updated DESC`

Comment: In msyql you probably want to use `REPLACE` instead of `UPDATE`/`INSERT` -> *REPLACE works exactly like INSERT, except that if an old row in the table has the same value as a new row for a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted.* http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html

Comment: or just use the primary key if it exists and you don't use the date for anything else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to accomplish it by adding a an `updated_at` DATETIME field to the MySQL table, which you update whenever a user saves the changes. Then in PHP, execute a query where you order the results by that date.